# What is the range of a standardized distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

When you normalize data, with scalar values, by dividing with the total number of observations, the range of data values is $[0,1]$. But I cannot figure out the range of data values after standardizing it - that is, subtract mean and divide with standard deviation. Can you help and explain why?

I am using the range of values after standardization to try to explain the following: "standardizing the inputs of a sigmoid would constrain them to the linear regime of the nonlinearity." - this makes me wonder what the author means by the quote. Do anyone have an idea?

To me, it would only make sense if the input values after standardization were in the range like $[0,1]$ but this is not the case after seeing the answer from Henry.

Comment: Dividing by the number of observations, i.e. $\frac{x_i}{n}$, will not restrict you to $[0,1]$ unless $x_i \in [0,n]$

Comment: @Henry Ahh yea, my bad. I meant dividing by the maximum value. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: OK - but then you seem to be assuming everything is non-negative

Comment: Yea, you did answer my question though, so all good :) That would also be the correct assumption for the problem I am working nice - nice catch tho

Answer (score 1):

If you have $n$ observations $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ with mean $\bar x$, standard deviation $s$, minimum $x_\min$ and maximum $x_\max$, then two common choices for "normalisation" or "standardisation" lead to

$$\dfrac{x_i-x_\min}{x_\max-x_\min} \in [0,1]$$ and together the rebased observations will have mean $\frac{\bar x-x_\min}{x_\max-x_\min}$ $($somewhere in $[0,1])$ and standard deviation $\frac{s}{x_\max-x_\min}$ $($no greater than $\frac12)$, with rebased values of $0$ and $1$ occurring so with width $1$, and

$$\dfrac{x_i-\bar x}{s} \in \left[-\sqrt{n-1}, \sqrt{n-1}\right]$$ $($ or  $\pm{\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}}$ depending on how you calculated $s)$, and together the rebased observations will have mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$, with the actual rebased range being $\left[\frac{x_\min-\bar x}{s}, \frac{x_\max-\bar x}{s}\right]$

Comment: Thank you very much I can use it more if considering the case where you standardize by subtracting the mean and divide by standard deviation - how does this relate to your answer?

Comment: @ThatGuy My second case of $\dfrac{x_i-\bar x}{s}$ is precisely "subtracting the mean and divide by standard deviation"

Comment: Ah of course. But does that part require that you first do the $\dfrac{x_i-x_\min}{x_\max-x_\min}$ transformation for every observation first?

Comment: @ThatGuy No - they are alternatives for rescaling and rebasing

Comment: Okay - one final thing: I am using the range of values after standardization to try to explain the following: "standardizing the inputs of a sigmoid would constrain them to
the linear regime of the nonlinearity." Sigmoid is the function $S(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$. However, with your beautiful answer, it seems like the range itself is not bounded and depends on the max and min value in the original observations - this makes me wonder what the author means by the quote

Comment: Do you have an idea?

Comment: @ThatGuy I suspect the quote is talking about the middle part of a [sigmoid curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) which can look almost linear and diagonally sloping while the tails will be almost flat.  Why this is desirable is not particularly clear: things like logistic regression and log-odds can handle the curve in a sensible way

Comment: Yes indeed I also think he is talking about the middle part but if you just stated that the range is not limit(assuming the original input is not limited in value) after standardizing the input, then why would the author say we would be restricted the linear regime which seems to be about $[-1,1]$?

Answer (score 0):

If you take the lowest and highest values of your original data, you can "standardize" those values by subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard deviation.  The transformed lowest value and transformed highest value will be the new range.